Can't Install Package argon2_cffi_bindings offline?
I'm installing argon2_cffi_bindings package in python offline using the CMD prompt:
pip.exe install --no-index --find-links=***\argon2_cffi_bindings-21.2.0-pp38-pypy38_pp73-win_amd64.whl argon2-cffi-bindings
and encounter this error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement argon2-cffi-bindings (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for argon2-cffi-bindings, when installing offline using pip.exe install --no-index --find-links=***\argon2_cffi_bindings-21.2.0-pp38-pypy38_pp73-win_amd64.whl argon2-cffi-bindings

My Python verson is 3.12 and the package website said that it is supported. As instructed, I upgraded all package such as cffi, setuptools, pip.  However, the error still persists. How to solve this problem to install the package offline. (I can't use pip online)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline In addition to runtime dependencies that pip download gives you you also need to download build-time dependencies: https://github.com/hynek/argon2-cffi-bindings/blob/main/pyproject.toml#L2-L6


My Python verson is 3.12 and the package website said that it is supported.

But you've downloaded a wheel that is for PyPy 3.8, which is not compatible with (presumably CPython) Python 3.12.
You'll want https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/2c/e34e47c7dee97ba6f01a6203e0383e15b60fb85d78ac9a15cd066f6fe28b/argon2_cffi_bindings-21.2.0-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl which is compatible with x64 Windows CPython 3.6 and newer.
You can also just install it with pip install ./argon2_cffi_bindings-21.2.0-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl then.
