IPython cannot be installed
I tried to Install Ipython on an offline computer using the whl file.
I got this error message.
ERROR: Package 'ipython' requires a different Python: 3.9.6 not in '>=3.10'
What do i do?
I cannot simply upgrade the python on the machine. Are ther older versions of Ipyhton, because I couldn't find any on PyPI, that indicated they were compatible with older Python versions.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

pip that you will be using for pip download must be the same as on your offline host: The same Python version, the same OS, the same processor architecture.
