Generate Python 2.7 dependency tree for offline installation
I need to install the dateutil Python library to run a script at work.
The problem is that our machines do not have internet access so we cannot use pip2.7 to install the dependencies. What we can do is to get the modules offline and install them manually.
I've read about pipdeptree which might be interesting on getting the dependency tree. But I also want to be able to download all the dependencies in my local machine and upload them to the server so I can install all the modules offline.
We are using RHEL 8.6, so the python-dateutil package is not available. Only the python3-dateutil.
I don't get paid well enough to migrate a whole codebase.
As a consideration, we do not have root access and we should not install rpm packages.
I've tried downloading the dateutil installer, but it fails as it lacks some dependencies it cannot get because there is no internet connection.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Conlusion: python-dateutil only require one package six >=1.5
You can check source code
https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/master/setup.cfg
