How can I build / distribute / install Python packages with limited access to packages from PyPI?
At my workplace pip is not able to access the outside world to download packages. I'm not sure what system exactly is preventing this, but ideally I shouldn't be installing any old packages from the internet anyway. The only way I can install packages from online is to download a source distribution or wheel from the PyPI site or from the package's github and run pip install --no-deps <package path> so that pip doesn't attempt to go online for dependencies which would just hang for a long time and then fail.
I am developing some tools for my own use, and would like to package and distribute them to other members of my team so that they can be installed from a tarball or wheel, and also not require them to go online and pull more dependencies manually. The tools I'm writing are using the standard library so they don't require any online dependencies.
I'm leaning towards disregarding deprecation and using the setuptools versions of the now-removed distutils module, and writing a setup.py file for my package. However, this is deprecated or at least seems heavily discouraged. The setuptools user guide gives instructions for using the build package, but this package has a set of dependencies, and some of those have their own dependencies, and manually installing all of those packages by hand is a serious headache.
At the top-level build requires:

colorama (this feels like it should be optional)
importlib-metadata
packaging
pyproject_hooks
tomli

and some of these have their own list of dependencies.
Does anyone in a similarly restricted environment have a preferred method for building and installing internal packages? If so, what is your process?
In an ideal world I could just install all of the dependencies I need with no problem, but I understand that has security implications and I don't think I'll be able to make any sort of exceptions for pip's access being blocked.
What I've Tried
I have read documentation for various Python packaging methods, and the simplest I could find that isn't "deprecated" still requires the build package, which as I've said requires a large-enough tree of dependencies that installing them all manually is out of the question and still is in a gray area of acceptability for security reasons.
The setuptools documentation recommends against the use of setup.py: setuptools quickstart
The latest version of Python officially removes distutils from the standard library and continuing to use setup.py builds with modules from setuptools seems to be discouraged for the most part PEP 0632

This https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758 is not the only way but it's surely the simplest, the most convenient. Download packages with recursive dependencies on a connected host, move to the offline host. The connected host must run the same platform (Python version, OS, processor architecture); or use a virtual machine, emulator, container with the same platform.

Thanks for the pointer. I'm more interested in minimizing dependencies than I am in circumventing network restrictions at my workplace. As I said, I'm attempting to package code which has no dependencies outside the python standard library, and so I'd like to avoid installing anything beyond the absolute bare minimum from the internet.

In terms of build backend I believe flit has no dependencies. If you already have setuptools around, no need to switch to a different build backend, you can use setuptools without a setup.py but with a pyproject.toml just fine (it is the recommend way). -- Then if you have pip lying around you can use the pip wheel command to create wheels, no need to download and install the build tool to create wheels.

When working on sensitive or air-gapped systems, we use pip download <pkg> which will download the given package and its dependencies; obviously using an approved internet-enabled PC. Zip (or tar.gz) the downloaded wheels into an archive, and move that to the sensitive environment, and unpack. Then we use pip install <pkg>.whl --find-links /path/to/un-zipped_archive --no-index to install the package and its dependencies.  The --find-links argument tells pip where (in which directory) the dependencies can be found. The --no-index argument basically tells pip to stay offline.

This will get build (and its dependencies) downloaded and installed for you. Then, just write your pyproject.toml to create your wheel (or sdist) for your team. Once you start using it, you'll likely find that build and pyproject.toml are much easier to use than the old distutils and setup.py method.

@s3dev if I were able to use pip download, that would be a fine solution. Unfortunately pip appears to have no access to the outside world from my machine, hence downloading packages through my web browser manually. While the security implications of still being able to download anything from sites that aren't outright blocked on my office's network are certainly up for discussion, the fact remains that I can't use any help from pip in downloading the required files.

Understood.  In our situation, we have dedicated PCs (laptops) that are allowed online (even tethered to a phone) to perform the downloads. The downloaded wheels are then security checked. If they pass (and usually they do), we transfer the wheels to the sensitive environment for installation. Or, we put them in a dedicated (offline) pip repository, to which our local pip is configured to use.

We aren't really a python shop, so we don't really have any infrastructure in place around it other than having some vetted versions of python stored on the network. I'm sure it would be possible to get some things set up, but it wouldn't be a straightforward or rapid process.

Forget the local piprepo - that's obviously beyond your scope. However, the other comments are worth considering.  We've been developing Python projects for about 10 years in an isolated (sensitive) environment, and have found this method to be reliable.

yes, flit looks like a good choice if it indeed has no dependencies. @sinoroc would you convert your comment to an answer?

I was hopeful about flit, but of its dependencies, requests has its own set and it reaches the point of being ridiculous to manually download and install them all from PyPI. I may just ignore the warnings about not running setup.py standalone, since I don't see any other way without having to download everything I need at home and email it to myself at the office. That might look suspicious.

In my situation it seems that the most straightforward course of action is to ignore the fact that directly using setup.py is discouraged and do it anyway. With setup.py importing setup from setuptools I'm able to build a package that can be installed with pip by running python setup.py sdist
Of the suggestions in the comments this seems to be only way to build a package that only requires installation of setuptools if it isn't already installed.
I would still like a more modern and elegant solution, but that may not be possible due to whatever is restricting pip's access to the internet.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
