# Pip install on Chinese server ssl error

Tags: python, django, ssl, pip

I'm trying to install Django on a Chinese server on Ubuntu 12.04.

Trying to run `pip install django`and I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.pyton.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django
```

Complete `pip.log` is:

```
Downloading/unpacking django

  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/django
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/django: <urlopen error _ssl.c:489: The handshake operation timed out>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/django when looking for download links for django
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/: The read operation timed out
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for django
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/

  URLs to search for versions for django:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: timed out
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/django/ when looking for download links for django
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django

No distributions at all found for django
```

I've read that this could be system time issue with the ssl, do you guys have any idea on how I can solve this? Do I need to set a sepcific system time in order to be able to install packages using pip?

Thanks.

Comment: dowload the zip file and manually install from django site. or do git clone and install. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/install/

Comment: Yep, that works. Just wondering why this issue arises? I have done this thing 100 times and never before stumbled upon this.

Comment: might be u r behind some proxy or some downtime at the server side try after some time.

Comment: @loki still doesn't work. Actually I can't pip install anything which is quite strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pypi.pyton.org domain seems to be blocked by the Great Firewall Of China, see more info here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Shield_Project.
A great site for testing if websites work from inside China is http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org, the site confirms that it's blocked:
http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org/index.php?siteurl=http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org.

What you could do is

1. Try using the Ubuntu default packages instead and install Django with apt-get ( $ sudo apt-get install python-django)
2. Download the pip archive for Django to a host in another country and then copy that file to your server in China. More info to do this with pip archives can be found here [Installing Python packages from local file system folder with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-with-pip).

Answer (score 4):

Great Firewall has been upping its game recently, even against VPNs. You may end up needing to use a different (local) mirror for pip install. At time of writing, this one worked for me:

```
pip install [YOUR_PACKAGE] -i http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple --trusted-host mirrors.aliyun.com
```

Comment: This works! When will China be opened to the world is unknown to the world.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can run pip with global proxied [goagent](https://code.google.com/p/goagent/) or through VPN.

**UPDATE:** http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org/ may report wrong, it tells me no servers were able to reach Baidu just now!(which is definitely accessable)