# Can't pip ,the command on mac , search packages in local path not on the net

Tags: python, macos, pip

I have already download some packages,

but Terminal always search those packages on the net when i use the command

pip install package

for instance,

i want to install pygame (pygame-1.9.1-release………….dmg)which already in my mac and the path would be /Users/**/Downloads/

Install pygame:

$ pip install pygame

Terminal show the following message to me:
Downloading/unpacking pygame-1.9.1
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pygame-1.9.1
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pygame-1.9.1
Storing complete log in /Users/Crayon_277/.pip/pip.log

So, does it really work only that way?

Comment: Mostly answered here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-with-pip

Comment: However, pip doesn't really support `.dmg` format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use python on Mac seriously consider using virtual environments. This will really save you a lot of time trying to fixing issues like that.

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/