# Package in pypi can not be found

Tags: python, pip, asterisk, pypi

I am trying to install `starpy`:

```
» pip install starpy
Downloading/unpacking starpy
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement starpy
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for starpy
Storing debug log for failure in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

Ok, fair enough, the package is not in `pypi`, life is hard, yadayadayada. But:

```
» pip search starpy
starpy                    - Twisted Protocols for interaction with the Asterisk PBX
```

And it is indeed [there](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/starpy/1.0.0a11)

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any package to download in that page.
Why don't you triy install it manually downloading here: http://starpy.sourceforge.net/
and running:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: You are right, there is no package to download. What does that mean? Somebody publishes a package to pypi, but offers no download? Makes no sense.

Comment: Anyway, I have lots of packages that I need to install. Most are in pypi, and for some I have special rules to install them (like for starpy, the one rule you mention), which makes my dependencies difficult to manage. I would like to move to pypi for all my dependencies. I will have to package starpy myself.

Comment: Maybe he removed it after publish... I don't know.
Related to your other question, is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-with-pip

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but is not really good for me, because I need to: clone the repo, cd to the directory, build, and then do pip install. And this for a **single package**. What other dance will I have to do for the other missing packages? I *can* do that, but compare that to: pip install -r requirements.txt. I just want to have a requirements.txt with all packages and use that. No hassle, no special building of packages, no nothing. This is not a one-off install. I want to have this for deploy. I really prefer to package the missing packages myself and push them to pypi.

Comment: You don't need to go the directory and build, you can clone de repo and run: pip install -e starpy-1.0.0a13 <- path where the setup.py is located.
It should be enough to install.