# pip install not working

Tags: python, installation, pip, anaconda

I want to install a package called ceODBC. Currently, I'm using Anaconda 2.0 version of Python 2.7. I used the following command:

```
Y:\Python\pip install ceODBC-2.0.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
```

but got the following error message:

```
Downloading/unpacking ceODBC-2.0.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement ceODBC-2.0.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for ceODBC-2.0.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe 
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\sam\pip\pip.log
```

The log file looks like this:

```
C:\Anaconda\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 09/25/14 21:33:49
Downloading/unpacking ceODBC-2.0.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/ceODBC-2.0.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ceODBC-2.0.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe/:    
404 Client Error: Not Found
```

Can anyone tell me what can be the reason? Y: is a shared drive, and I could install this  using the same process on another computer.

Thanks!

Comment: the reason is because ceODBC-2.0.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe doesn't exist in the repository, try to download your package from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Python packages from local file system folder with pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-with-pip)

Comment: I downloaded it again and replaced the former with this new one. Still I'm getting the same error

Comment: Have you tried actually running the installer?  If your python is registered with windows and is 64-bit 2.7 then it should just work.

Comment: This looks like a possible proxy issue. If you're in a proxied environment, you can set http_proxy and https_proxy.