# django - download and install django rest framework

Tags: python, django, pip, django-rest-framework

I am a beginner in django and did the basic tutorials on the official website.

I want to learn the django rest framework, and I saw that there is also a great tutorials here - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#requirements.

One thing I couldn't figure out - How do I install the framework and the other necessary things for it? I am working offline so I need to download all the libraries/packages manually and than install them. (cant use pip install and github clone)

An explanation for what do I need to download and how to install it in order to use the django rest framework would be highly appreciated :)

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand...if you can download a package for offline use, you can use `pip` to install for offline use...

Comment: hanks for you answer. the computer i am downloading from is not the one I am working on. so I want to know what do I nned to download and takes to the other computer.. saw this page - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorestframework/3.1.1#downloads, is this what I need? and there are also two files, not sure which one

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-with-pip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're a little confused about how `pip` works. Installing an application with `pip` *will* allow you to use it offline.

As per [the official repo](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/tree/master#installation):

```
$ pip install djangorestframework
```

And then add `'rest_framework'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'rest_framework',
)
```

You can now use DRF offline.

**EDIT**: If the machine you're developing on doesn't have the ability to connect to the internet, you can `clone` the github repo, copy it to your offline machine, and then run:

```
pip install -e /srv/pkg
```

...where `/srv/pkg` is the top-level directory where **setup.py** exists.

Comment: okay thanks. just want to make sure, the /srv/pkg is the directory of the rest-framrwork zip (uncomprassed off course) in my off-line machine right? where the setup.py? and also, I guess the pip install -e means that its local on the computer? thanks a lot

Comment: and one more question - is the rest-framework from github is all I need to install in order to use it? are there any other necessary things to do?

Comment: **setup.py** will be in the uncompressed folder of the app. You need to replace `srv/pkg` with the absolute path to the **setup.py** file in the package.

Comment: okay.. meaning somethong like dir/setup.py right? or to the folder that contains setup.py