# Controlling PYTHONPATH ordering in PyCharm to make the Source Folders are searched first

Tags: python, pycharm, pythonpath

I create a projectname package, and use PyCharm to debug the code in it. 
I also use venv for setting up Python environment for the package. I follow the standard package structure as follows.

```
.
├── NAME
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── arith.py
│   └── arith.py
├── bin
│   └── app.py
├── build
│   ├── bdist.macosx-10.11-intel
│   └── lib
│       └── NAME
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── arith.py
├── dist
│   └── projectname-0.1-py2.7.egg
├── docs
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── arith_tests.py
```

Then, I imported the project into PyCharm.
In Project:sekelton, I marked NAME/tests as source folders, and build/dist as excluded folders.

I also run `python setup.py install` to build and install the generated egg file into the venv's site-package directory.

[image]

The issue is that the egg file installed in site-package is called first as the PYTHONPATH shows from `import sys; print sys.path`:

```
['/python/structure/projects/skeleton/bin',
 'python/structure/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/projectname-0.1-py2.7.egg',  <== egg file is searched first
 'python/structure/projects/skeleton/NAME',    <==
```

This is pretty annoying as I can't debug the code with PyCharm, and when I modified the code, I had to run `python setup.py install` again to update the egg file. I may be able to circumvent this issue by removing the egg file from the Project Interpreter setup, but I think changing the order should be the better option.

[image]

How can I change the PYTHONPATH order in PyCharm so that the local Source Folders are searched first?

### EDIT

The PyCharm shows an error message when I tried to remove the package from the  Project Interpreter setup, but it's false positives, as PyCharm successfully removes the egg file, and updates the easy-install.pth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pip install -e NAME`,  will make the `projectname.egg-link` that points to the NAME directory, and update the `easy-install.pth`. I think this is better approach than `python setup.py`, and solves the PYTHONPATH problem.

```
skeleton> pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///python/structure/projects/skeleton
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nose in /python/structure/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from projectname==0.1)
Installing collected packages: projectname
  Running setup.py develop for projectname
Successfully installed projectname
```

With this approach, the egg is not in PYTHONPATH.

```
['/python/structure/projects/skeleton/bin',     
'/python/structure/projects/skeleton/NAME',
```

Even better, we can remove the package with  `pip uninstall projectname`.

```
pip uninstall projectname
Uninstalling projectname-0.1:

python/structure/projects/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/projectname.egg-link
Proceed (y/n)? y
    Successfully uninstalled projectname-0.1
```

I got hints from [Installing Python packages from local file system folder with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-with-pip)