# pip not installing entry_points as executables

Tags: python, bash, pip, setup.py

I'm trying to create a package of my own. The package is very simple, it has one python module and one bash script. I wan both of them to be installed under `/usr/local/bin` so that they can be directly executed.

Here's my `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='deploy',
    .
    .
    .
    install_requires=['pyyaml', 'cot', 'jsonschema'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'cloud_config = cloud_config:main',
        ],
    },
    scripts=['deploy.sh'],
)
```

Here's excerpt from output of `pip install ...`:

```
running install_scripts
    copying build/scripts-2.7/deploy.sh -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7.10/bin
    changing mode of /usr/local/lib/python2.7.10/bin/deploy.sh to 755
    Installing cloud_config script to /usr/local/lib/python2.7.10/bin
```

With this, I'm not able to invoke either the python or the bash script directly.

Any ideas?

Edit: I'm running the `pip` on `Ubuntu 16.04.1` machine. Just tried to install the same package on a `Ubuntu 14.04` machine and behavior is as expected. `cloud_config.py` and `deploy.sh` both get installed to `/usr/local/bin` and I can invoke both from anywhere on the system.

Comment: Ubuntu heavily patches pip; I'm not surprised they changed behaviour here too.

Comment: That's absurd @MartijnPieters. How does one go about creating a package that installs properly on all platforms?

Comment: I've just tried to create a package based on your `setup.py` and deploy to clean Ubuntu 16.04 Vagrant box - all works fine. If you would provide more information it might help to reproduce the issue. Maybe something with versions? Which version of setuptools do you use for assembly? Which are the pip and setuptools on target machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it to work. I had to remove the pip package that was installed by apt.

```
sudo apt remove python-pip
```

And then install pip again according to instructions on their website - https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/.

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Looks like pip from Ubuntu's default repository is not same as one distributed by pypi.

Answer (score 3):

Two options I can think of, first,check that pip is pointing in the right place.  So try:

```
which python
```

mine says:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

yours will be different, change the path accordingly to 
 then make sure the PATH is properly set, so:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin/python:${PATH}
```

Reinstall pip and try again.
Failing that, a workaround might be to not use pip in this instance and try:

```
python setup.py install
```

which will use your default python path (not pip) and should install to:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Mine also says `/usr/bin/python`. See my answer below to see what worked. I still have no idea why default pip doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
```

e.g.

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=/usr/local/bin" pyFooBar
```

Comment: Aren't entries under `entry_points -> console_scripts` supposed to be installed in the `PATH` so they're callable from anywhere?

Comment: According to this documentation for python packaging - http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html

Answer (score 1):

I also found I could install a package and it appeared to be successful, but the `entry_points` scripts weren't in my PATH. Turned out that pip silently failed to install them.

Try running `setup.py install` directly. Doing that showed me access errors when trying to install the scripts into `/usr/local/bin` even though `pip install -e .` showed no errors. ([See more about using -e.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20043907/79125))

The solution to my problem was to use `--prefix`:

```
pip install --prefix ~/apps -e .
```

And `~/apps/bin` is in my `$PATH`. To install to /usr/local/bin, you'd either have to change its permissions or run pip as root.

Answer (score 0):

`console_scripts` does not work with old versions of pip.  pip 10.0.1 is too old. pip 19.0.3 is sufficiently new.