# Installing your own Python Package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-wheel

I have defined a few classes in a Python file. I know I can import it into a given script so long as that file is in the same directory as my script; however, I would like to be able to install that file as a package so I can import it without having to place it in the current directory everytime I want to use it.

Essentially, is there a way to pip install a package you've written yourself so it can be imported in a Python script without existing in the same directory as the script?

Any help or advice in this arena would be greatly appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Python packages from local file system folder with pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-with-pip)

Answer (score 2):

You will need [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/setupscript.html)

a minimal example for your setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
  name='foo',
  version='1.0',
  py_modules=['foo'],
)
```

Your folder should look like:

```
[some_folder]
  | [foo]
  |   | __init__.py
  |   | the_code_you_already_wrote.py
  |
  | setup.py
```

in the **__init__.py** you can simply write:

```
from the_code_you_already_wrote import *
```

Comment: pypa suggests `setuptools` over distutils fwiw

Comment: oh just copypasted it from the python docs, i always forget they keep the legacy stuff there :)