# installing the python library pygplates on MacOSX

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install the PyGplates python library on MacOSX. This can be found here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gplates/files/pygplates/beta-revision-12/ using the instructions here: http://www.gplates.org/docs/pygplates/pygplates_getting_started.html#installing-pygplates

The contents of the downloaded .zip is a folder containing .dylib and a .so file, amongst others.

My question is how do I install this library? In the instructions it simply says I must add the path either as an environmental variable in each script or in the startup script, both of which I have tried but I have not been successful.

PyGplates is not available via Pip or Easy install as far as I am aware.

Comment: Have you tried installing it with pip like its described in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-with-pip

Comment: There is no 'setup.py' (or similar) as far as I can tell in the download. Is this required for this approach?