# Installing Python packages from local file system folder with pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install python packages from the local file system with `pip` as discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-to-virtualenv-with-pip/15031843).

I have used `pip2pi` as suggested in the accepted answer in the above question.

```
dmanna@ubuntu:~$ mkdir -p pyt/pkg
dmanna@ubuntu:~$ pip2tgz pyt/pkg/ patroni[zookeeper]
```

The downloaded packages

```
dmanna@ubuntu:~$ ls /home/dmanna/pyt/pkg/
cdiff-1.0.tar.gz
certifi-2018.4.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl
chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
idna-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
kazoo-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
patroni-1.4.4.tar.gz
prettytable-0.7.2.tar.bz2
psutil-5.4.6.tar.gz
psycopg2-2.7.4.tar.gz
python_dateutil-2.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
pytz-2018.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz
requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
tzlocal-1.5.1.tar.gz
urllib3-1.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Then when I am trying to install the required package from the above local directory. It is giving me the below error

```
dmanna@ubuntu:~$ sudo pip install --no-index --find-links=pyt/pkg/patroni-1.4.4.tar.gz patroni[zookeeper]
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Downloading/unpacking patroni[zookeeper]
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/patroni/setup.py) egg_info for package patroni

  Installing extra requirements: 'zookeeper'
Downloading/unpacking urllib3>=1.19.1,!=1.21 (from patroni[zookeeper])
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement urllib3>=1.19.1,!=1.21 (from patroni[zookeeper])
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for urllib3>=1.19.1,!=1.21 (from patroni[zookeeper])
Storing debug log for failure in /home/dmanna/.pip/pip.log
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Python - 2.7.6
PIP - 1.5.4
Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--find-links=pyt/pkg
```

Find links in the directory, not in the `patroni-1.4.4.tar.gz` archive.

Comment: One more query. If I run `sudo pip install --no-index --find-links=file://pyt/pkg/ patroni[zookeeper]` then it is failing with the error `Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Downloading/unpacking patroni[zookeeper]
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement patroni[zookeeper]
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for patroni[zookeeper]
Storing debug log for failure in /home/dmanna/.pip/pip.log
`. Any idea why it is failing with `file:///` ?

Comment: Why do you think it should work at all? It must be either a directory or an html file with links. `file://` URL is neither.