# python does not recognize packages with __init__.py

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

I want to access A.py from D.py (3 levels up). I have added an **init**.py to all the directories in this project to initialize them as packages. When I try the following in D.py:

```
from test1 import A

A.hi()
```

I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test1'
```

I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio Code and python 3.9.6 and I even added all the test1, test2, test3 folders to path variable. I think it's worth mentioning that Visual Studio does seem to recognize these folders as packages as it shows them in the dropdown list when typing module names at import.

[image]

**EDIT:**
I have managed to access a Z.py created in test1 from test3 D.py with this:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("C:\\Users\\myusername\\Desktop\\testdbconnection"))

from test1 import Z
Z.hi()
```

This folder was already in Windows Path, I added it myself. Why did Python not recognize it before?

Also, I can't access anything else than what is in test1 with this.

- If i want to access A.py and B.py i need to append to path
  C:\Users\myusername\Desktop,
- if i want to access test2 C.py i need to append to path
  C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\testdbconnection\test1
- and so on...

Comment: The `test1` package needs to be installed in the search path in order to be able to import it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to locally develop a python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248505/how-to-locally-develop-a-python-package)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868733/how-to-access-a-module-from-outside-your-file-folder-in-python)

Comment: How are you running this code? ``test1`` is only available as a package when explicitly added to the search path *or* ``D.py`` is run as ``test1.test2.test3.D`` (i.e. as part of the package).

Comment: Hey, no, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248505/how-to-locally-develop-a-python-package did not answer my question. I am just trying to access a script in the root directory for one of my bigger projects. It is a mailing script that i want to reuse. 
This, however, came a bit closer to solving my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868733/how-to-access-a-module-from-outside-your-file-folder-in-python

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me.

```
from pathlib import Path
desktop = Path(__file__).absolute().parent.parent.parent.parent.parent
sys.path.append(str(desktop))
```

This appends the containing folder of testdbconnection which is Desktop in my case to the Path variable. The first `.parent` returns the directory of the file and the remaining 4 `.parent` return the Desktop folder. I think it is best practice not to include Desktop in the Path variable but to create another parent folder to contain testdbconnection.
Finally, convert the `Path` object to str and append it to `sys.path`.

Using the absolute path of the file ensures the path is the same even if I run my python script from test3 (python D.py) or from test2 (python test3/D.py) or from anywhere else really.