# Install directly from a remote git repository on a network drive

Tags: python, git

I have some core Python packages that I develop for my team.
The package directory is setup in standard way;

```
/mypkg
    /mypkg
    /tests
    README.txt
    LICENSE.txt
    setup.py
    .gitignore
```

Now, because these are for internal use only, and for other company-sensitive reasons, my remote git repository is just a shared network drive;

```
//svr/path/to/remote/repo.git
```

The core packages are relativley stable, and are updated with bug fixes and new features from time to time.

I also develop a set of tools which are distributed to team members. These team members all have access to the shared drive location.

Can they `pip install` directly from the shared drive?

I have seen answers with stuff like;

`pip install git+https://github/user/repo.git`

and I know about

`pip install --find-links ...`

Can they somehow be combined??? It would be cool?
I know that an easier solution would be clone the git repo and then run `setup.py` but some of the end-users are non tech-savvy and also may not have git installed (as we are on Windows)

If I could simply add a line in the requirements.txt file which pointed at the shared drive that would be nice...

**UPDATE:**

If I use

`pip install git+file://path/to/remote/repo.git`

it works as I would like - but would this approach require git to be installed?

Comment: It should work with `pip install --find-links file:///svr/path/to/remote/repo.git`

Comment: That was my initial thought, but when I try it I get `ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (maybe you meant pip install <then the path i just entered...???>`

Comment: Actually, come to think of it this won't work, it will only work with already packaged code (i.e. setup.py has already been run). Have a look at these two posts, they should help you along: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-to-virtualenv-with-pip, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-to-install-packages-using-pip-according-to-the-requirements-txt-file-from-a

Comment: @karl, thank you. Yeah I know about installing when a source distribution is already created. The thing is, I don't really want to push the packaged code into the repository - this seems to go against the ethos of source-controlling stuff which can just be regenerated. However, if this is an accepted approach I could perhaps do this...