# Getting error if installing the python packages through loop from local folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-import, lib

I am trying to install some packages through python code using loop, **but at once only one package get install**.

> Got below error on next package.
>
> ```
> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\akshay~1.sha\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-req-tracker-aoybzz\\f37aad13bd20c8b1e66a004a7c01edf203f7e46ba784c9954fe935f7'
> ```

If I run the script again it will install the second package and throw error for the third. If I run it third time it will install the third, I want to install all the packages in one go, please help. Below is the code

===========================================================================

```
import os

from pip._internal import main as pipmain

PACKAGES = {'pymongo': 'pymongo-3.4.0', 'pexpect': 'pexpect-4.6.0', 'pathlib': 'pathlib-1.0.1'}

def install_dependency(pkg_name, crnt_path):
    pkg_path = os.path.join(crnt_path, "dependencies\\"+pkg_name+"\\")
    print("Installing package from local...", pkg_name)
    pipmain(["install", pkg_path])

def check_dependecies():
    current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    print(PACKAGES.keys())
    for package_name in PACKAGES.keys():
        try:
            __import__(package_name, globals=globals())
            print("================> Package imported successfully", package_name)
        except ImportError as import_error:
            print("Package not present", import_error)
            install_dependency(PACKAGES[package_name], current_path)
            print("================> Package imported successfully", package_name)
            __import__(package_name, globals=globals())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_dependecies()
```

Comment: Does the code finish successfully each time you try, even if you have to rerun it many times?

Comment: Yes, finish successfully but only install the package which is not installed already and give error for next packages. Also I am installing these package via folders in my system

Comment: When it does install successfully, is the package name the main or dependent one?

Comment: Main package...

Comment: Does another for loop inside the first for loop but outside the try except work? `for i in range(3)` It will skip to the next one if it doesn't install after 3 tries.

Comment: Same error, also the outer loop will iterate only one time

Comment: Hmm... Maybe try looping the outer loop too? I guess looping should work...

Comment: Not working, Same error, only very first pkg got installed :-(

Comment: Which line was the problematic line? I found [this example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26393695/10638232) with a different approach that might work...

Comment: It worked when I put all three installation in different files and trigger them with "os" command from the base file. I don't know why It not worked from the loop or from the same file

Comment: Looks like I'm not too sure on what's wrong anymore. I guess you'll have to trigger them independently...

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for helpful questions. :D

Comment: @GeeTransit Thanx man....

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and i've solved this using a workaround.

We know that we can't install several packages in a for loop using pip, but we also know that we can install multiple package at a time!

That's how I proceed:

1. loop through our packages looking for their presence, if not we save them inside a dict `{pkg_name: pkg_id}` (eg: `{'pymongo': 'pymongo-3.4.0'}`)
2. Create a list `pkg2install` composed by only `pkg_id` (eg: `['pymongo-3.4.0', 'pexpect-4.6.0']`)
3. Use `pipmain` to install them all in one shot: `pipmain(['install', *pkg2install])

Your code reviewed:

```py
from pip._internal import main as pipmain

PACKAGES = {'pymongo': 'pymongo', 'pexpect': 'pexpect', 'pathlib': 'pathlib'}


def check_dependecies():
    missing_pkgs = {}

    for package_name in PACKAGES.keys():
        try:
            __import__(package_name, globals=globals())
            print("================> Package imported successfully", package_name)

        except ImportError as import_error:
            print("Package not present", import_error)

            missing_pkgs.update({package_name: PACKAGES[package_name]})

    pkgs2install = missing_pkgs.values()

    status = pipmain(["install", *pkgs2install])

    if status == 0:
        print("================> Missing packages installed successfully", pkgs2install)    

        for pkg in missing_pkgs.keys():
            __import__(pkg, globals=globals())
            print("================> Package imported successfully", pkg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_dependecies()
```

The output it generates:

```sh
Package not present No module named 'pymongo'
Package not present No module named 'pexpect'
================> Package imported successfully pathlib
Collecting pymongo
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/8c/ec46f4aa95515989711a7893e64c30f9d33c58eaccc01f8f37c4513739a2/pymongo-3.9.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (378kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 378kB 4.4MB/s 
Collecting pexpect
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/3e/377007e3f36ec42f1b84ec322ee12141a9e10d808312e5738f52f80a232c/pexpect-4.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ptyprocess>=0.5 (from pexpect)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/29/605c2cc68a9992d18dada28206eeada56ea4bd07a239669da41674648b6f/ptyprocess-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pymongo, ptyprocess, pexpect
Successfully installed pexpect-4.7.0 ptyprocess-0.6.0 pymongo-3.9.0
================> Missing packages installed successfully dict_values(['pymongo', 'pexpect'])
================> Package imported successfully pymongo
================> Package imported successfully pexpect
```

**Note:** I didn't use version or local packages, but the mechanism should remain the same

I hope this is helpful despite being 11 months late.