# Python not finding module when running AWS sam local invoke

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I have just started using AWS serverless using SAM and have run into the problem below:

SAM invoke can't seem to find a python module that my lambda handler is importing but I can otherwise import that module.

The **structure** of my project is:

root-dir/

- mymodulename/

  - mymodule.py
- aws/

  - sam/

    - template.yaml
    - packaged.yaml
    - myawsservice/

      - app.py
    - test/

      - test_event.json

I am working in a python3.6 virtual environment and I have installed my python package (mymodulename) using setup tool:

```
python setup.py develop
```

So if I do a pip freeze in my virtual environment I see:

```
Pillow==6.0.0
PyPDF2==1.26.0
reportlab==3.5.20
mymodulename==0.5.0
```

Also if I go:

```
cd root-dir/aws/sam/
python

>>> import mymodulename
```

This succeeds. So it is on the python path.

But when I invoke sam locally i.e.:

```
sam local invoke MyAWSServiceFunction --event ../sam/test/test_event.json
```

I get the **error** message:

```
2019-05-02 09:19:17 Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2019-05-02 09:19:18 Invoking app.lambda_handler (python3.6)

Fetching lambci/lambda:python3.6 Docker container image......
2019-05-02 09:19:19 Mounting /home/myname/root-dir/aws/sam/myawsservice as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: 245daefe-ecfb-4530-9d15-cf07f55e0f3d Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'mymodulename'
END RequestId: 245daefe-ecfb-4530-9d15-cf07f55e0f3d
REPORT RequestId: 245daefe-ecfb-4530-9d15-cf07f55e0f3d Duration: 31 ms 
Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 19 MB

{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app'"}
```

Here is the code for my **app.py**:

```
from mymodulename.mymodule import mymodulefunction

def lambda_handler(event, context):    
    return mymodulefunction(event['body'])
```

I can run the code above from my unit test just not from the sam invoke environment.

**template.yaml:**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: > something

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  MyAWSServiceFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: myawsservice/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
```

Help appreciated.

**EDIT**:

One workaround is to put the app.py, requirements.txt and template.yaml in the root directory and do:

```
sam build
```

This will store the 3rd party dependencies and my own python module together and template.py will now be able to find it during sam local invoke.

This is however not practical for bigger projects, and I guess the answer for now might be something like [this](https://medium.com/@nate_mitchell/serverless-packaging-user-defined-python-modules-41808776eae0). Although this is for a serverless.yaml. I'm not sure if SAM supports this syntax. Guessing no.

Comment: Have you tried using lambda layers? You can deploy 3rd party libs along with any other libs you create to a lambda layer and import that layer into your lambda function. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: Take a look if this post could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/76949855/2153237

Answer (score 6):

It's being a long time since this question was opened, but it might help to someone. How I fixed it:

- Move your code from `mymodulename/` to `mymodulename/mymodulename/__init__.py`
- In `mymodulename` create a `setup.py` who will be responsible for creating a package called `mymodulename`
- In your `requirements.txt` of your lambda function add this: `-e mymodulename/`

The `-e` references to your local code, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-to-virtualenv-with-pip/20043907#20043907) might helps also.

Comment: could you share your setup.py? I'm facing this same issue

Comment: from setuptools import setup

setup(
   name='mymodulename',
   version='1.0',
   description='A useful module',
   author='Your name',
   author_email='example@example.com',
   packages=['mymodulename'],  #same as name
   py_modules=['mymodulename'], # the py file name of your methods, like mymodulename/mymodulename/mymodulename.py
   install_requires=['pymongo', 'dnspython'], #external packages as dependencies
)

Comment: One more note: the function you define within mymodulename.py should be imported into __init__.py, like ' from .mymodulename import myfunction '

Comment: This would definitely help. https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-builders/blob/develop/tests/integration/workflows/python_pip/testdata/local-dependencies/setup.py