# Installing Python Packages From local File System

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install some of the packages (Example: openpyxl) from local file system, however pip installer is always looking package from pypi.org or pypi.python.org and not from the local path.

Below are the commands, I have used.

```
pip install openpyxl c:\users\test\openpyxl-2.6.3.tar.gz

easy_install openpyxl c:\users\test\openpyxl-2.6.3.tar.gz
```

After the above commands are executed:I get the below errors:

```
Searching for openpyxl
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/openpyxl/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/openpyxl/

Installer pointing to pypi.python.org and not the local filesystem.
```

Encountered in:

```
Operating System: Windows 10
Python Version: 3.7
Pip Version:10.0.1
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Python packages from local file system folder to virtualenv with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-to-virtualenv-with-pip)

Comment: Thanks, however I referred the above link before posting this question. I used the similar syntax while installing, however pip is trying to install from pypi.org and not from local drive. I don't want to use virtual environment or requirements.txt to install packages. I would like to install packages just simple like this pip install <package> localpath. Hope I have explained my question clearly.

Comment: There is clearly mentioned that `--no-index --find-links` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your command

```
pip install openpyxl c:\users\test\openpyxl-2.6.3.tar.gz
```

should be

```
pip install c:\users\test\openpyxl-2.6.3.tar.gz
```

as `pip install` accepts local paths to `.tar.gz` files directly.

Note that your `pip` is also quite outdated. You might want to consider upgrading it to the newest version

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I will updated my pip as well, thanks for pointing that