# tell pip install to *NEVER* go to the network and *ALWAYS* download from a local directory

Tags: python, pip

I'm running on a disconnected network. I have downloaded a collection of wheels (.whl) and .tar.gz files to `/mnt/dist/python`. I want to install `boto3` which is in the directory. All of the dependencies are also in the directory. However, when I tell pip to install either `boto3` or `boto-2.49.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` it tries to go to the network.

How do I tell it to install from `/mnt/dist/python` instead of going to the network?

Comment: I believe the first comment from this answer is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15031843/5430833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly modified version of what @Marek Piotrowski commented worked out for me. I just move to the folder where the `.whl` file was stored and then typed

```
pip install --no-index --find-links . boto-2.49.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```