# how to install a package into a conda env from source

Tags: python, server, pip, conda, offline

I have an anaconda `env` on an offline Ubuntu server. Initially, I downloaded Anaconda distribution with my laptop, moved it to the offline server and installed succesfully. Then I created a conda `env` using a laptop (which has an internet access) and installed all packages that I needed at that time. After that I moved that `env` folder to the server and now can use it.

However, I need a couple of more packages to be installed into that `env` on the server. I know that I can install them using my laptop again into  `env` and moving the `env` folder to the server. But I would like to do it the following way:

I download the package from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) site and copy/paste it into ***somewhere*** the `env` folder on the server and install using `pip install foo.tar.gz` or `pip install foo.whl`

Is it doable?

Comment: perhaps, this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63403161/tell-pip-install-to-never-go-to-the-network-and-always-download-from-a-local/63403430#63403430

Comment: @MiguelTrejo didn't help. Although `pip install` did install the package and `pip list` lists the package, it is not `import`ing