# How do I install python package on Jupyterlab

Tags: python

I'm unable to install package from github due to my organization's firewall policy. So I have downloaded the file & saved it under path/mypackage. Can you suggest me how do I install this package in my jupytelab 3.1.9

Comment: I find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-to-virtualenv-with-pip) to be very helpful.

Comment: I tried that link, before posting here. But it's not working. Please send me your mail id. I will share with you the code &  error message that I'm getting

Comment: This is not the place for personal communication, so let's share what the error is.

Comment: I used following code `pip install german_compound_splitter-master --no-index --find-links file:///home/work/TextCluster/german_compound_splitter-master` & I got following error message `Looking in links: `file:///home/work/TextCluster/german_compound_splitter-master
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement german_compound_splitter-master (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for german_compound_splitter-master`
I have downloaded the complete master from here https://github.com/repodiac/german_compound_splitter

Comment: To run from `jupyterlab`, prefix the command with an exclamation mark `!pip install...`

Comment: Still same error message

Comment: There is some [useful information](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#installing-from-local-archives) in the comments on the link you commented on. This is about all I can help you with.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I tried the following `py -m pip install --no-index --find-links=/home/work/TextCluster/german_compound_splitter-master setup.py` but I got following error `File "/tmp/ipykernel_2694/404947400.py", line 1
    py -m pip install --no-index --find-links=/home/jovyan/work/Textmining/german_compound_splitter-master/ setup.py
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
Am I doing anything wrong?