# Python Django requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, pip, requirements.txt

I have a `requirements.txt` file containing all my dependencies but it is not processed correctly :

After a `pip install -r requirements.txt`, I get the following `pip freeze` :

```
argparse==1.2.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

But when I do a pip install of :

```
numpy==1.6.2
Django==1.4.2
django-tastypie==0.9.14
pyes==0.19.1
```

And then run my `pip install -r requirements.txt` . Then it works.

Here is what my requirements.txt contains :

```
numpy==1.6.2
Django==1.4.2
django-tastypie==0.9.14
urllib3==1.5
pyes==0.19.1
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
MySQL-python==1.2.3
IMAPClient==0.9.1
Jinja2==2.6
Pillow==2.0.0
amqp==1.0.9
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==2.7.3.22
celery==3.0.16
django-celery==3.0.11
django-compressor==1.3
django-concurrency
django-extensions==1.1.1
https://codeload.github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/zip/master#egg=django-haystack
django-model-utils==1.2.0
django-multiforloop==0.2.1
django-social-auth==0.7.22
html5lib==0.95
httplib2==0.8
kombu==2.5.7
logilab-astng==0.24.2
logilab-common==0.59.0
oauth2==1.5.211
ordereddict==1.1
pycrypto==2.6
pylint==0.27.0
python-dateutil==1.5
python-openid==2.2.5
pytz==2013b
six==1.3.0
unittest2==0.5.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
xlrd==0.9.0
xmltodict==0.4.6
django-storages>=1.1.8
boto==2.8.0
lxml==3.1.0
pyelasticsearch==0.4.1
django-tastypie-elasticsearch==0.1.0
```

Would anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 7):

I tried this out and the problem is with django-tastypie-elasticsearch. There is a known issue, whereby installation with pip fails if Django hasn't been installed yet. Here is the issue report:

https://github.com/llonchj/django-tastypie-elasticsearch/issues/1

Looks like django-tastypie-elastic has only two contributors, so you're probably on your own. The good news is that it wasn't your fault!

Answer (score 3):

On mac:

To get your already installed dependencies

`pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`

from: [Automatically create requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684375/automatically-create-requirements-txt)

---

Then if you want to install them, and you are using a virtual environment

`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

from:
[How can I install packages using pip according to the requirements.txt file from a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-can-i-install-packages-using-pip-according-to-the-requirements-txt-file-from)

---

If you want to update them

> I just know how to do it with **pip-review**.
> https://pypi.org/project/pip-review/#description

`pip3 install pip-review` or `pip install pip-review`

then `pip-review --local --auto`

from:
[How to upgrade all Python packages with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip)

Answer (score 1):

The "https://codeload.github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/zip/master#egg=django-haystack" line is not a valid pip requirement. It should read "-e git+https://codeload.github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/zip/master#egg=django-haystack"

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bruno but that was unfortunately not the problem.