# how to install requirement.txt file in google collab in python?

Tags: python-3.x, requirements.txt

I have written this code in google collab in python:  !pip install -r requirements.txt
and getting this output:

Collecting astropy==2.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Downloading astropy-2.0.3.tar.gz (8.3 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8.3/8.3 MB 10.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Please help me to install requirments.txt file. I have downloaded this files from github as zipfile and then uploaded to google collab then unzip it.

when I tried to install each manually without version, it worked though some didn't. but it is a hassle to install each manually. i want to install the requirments.txt file directly

Comment: It would help if you provided the contents of your `requirements.txt` file

Comment: astropy==2.0.3
atomicwrites==1.3.0
attrs==19.1.0
boltons==19.1.0
certifi==2019.3.9
contextlib2==0.5.5
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.29.10
debtcollector==1.21.0
decorator==4.4.0
dit==1.2.3
importlib-metadata==0.17
joblib==1.2.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
llvmlite==0.29.0
matplotlib==3.1.0
more-itertools==7.0.0
networkx==2.3
numba==0.44.0
numpy==1.22.0
packaging==19.0
pandas==0.24.2
pbr==5.2.1
pluggy==0.12.0
POT==0.5.1
prettytable==0.7.2
progressbar==2.5
py==1.8.0
pyparsing==2.4.0
pytest==4.6.2
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-igraph==0.7.1.post6
python-louvain==0.13

Comment: louvain==0.6.1
pytz==2019.1
scikit-learn==0.21.2
scipy==1.3.0
six==1.12.0
sklearn==0.0
umap-learn==0.3.9
wcwidth==0.1.7
wrapt==1.11.1
zipp==0.5.1

Comment: github link:  https://github.com/zcang/SpaOTsc/blob/master/requirements.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after running `pip install -v -r requirements.txt` (with the -v switch to make the output more versbose) in a default Google Colab instance, it seems the `astropy` installation fails when looking for the Python library `collections.MutableSequence`, which apparently got moved to `collections.abc.MutableSequence` in Python 3.10, which is the Google Colab Python version.

In other words, that version of `astropy` is incompatible with Python 3.10. You'll need to either find a version that is, or see if you can run a different (compatible) version of Python in your Google Colab instance.

**Edit:**

As a workaround, try deleting the specific version numbers from your `requirements.txt` file. In other words, replace the 'astropy==2.0.3' by 'astropy' with no exact version. You could even do this programatically for your entire `requirements.txt` file using `sed` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73084902/5905029) (to a different question).

Comment: I gave it a go myself and successfully ran `pip install -r requirements.txt` on a versionless `requirements.txt`, but only after also installing a missing C library required by the Cython package using apt-get as follows: `!apt-get install libgmp3-dev`

Comment: thanks a lot. That helped me. I needed the exact version listed in the requirments.txt. thus why i have searched for python version that is compatible. for me that was 3.6.10. i created a virtual environment with python 3.6.10, then installed requirments.txt. in anaconda prompt, and from there launce the kernel.

Comment: Yes that sounds like exactly the right solution given the requirement of a specific astropy version. Well done.