# How to "pip install" latest versions of modules from requirements.txt neglecting the old versions written in REQUIREMENTs.TXT?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, virtualenv

I am working in Django. I want to install all the python modules which are the latest. What should in HAVE to do to update all the latest versions of modules?

> How to "pip install" the latest versions of modules from requirements.txt neglecting the old versions written in REQUIREMENTs.TXT?

Let's say, Inside requirements.txt is:

```
asn1crypto==1.0.1
astroid==2.3.1
```

so I want to install the latest version of:
`asn1crypto` and `astroid`

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean that your `requirements.txt` contains, for example, `Django==2.0` and `requests==1.5`, and you want to install the latest versions of both packages?

Comment: YEs bro. That's what I want....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrade python packages from requirements.txt using pip command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764549/upgrade-python-packages-from-requirements-txt-using-pip-command)

Comment: `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt` DIDn't worked instead it started to install Modules denoted in req..ments.text

Comment: I didn't say anything about that command. That's in the linked _question_. Take a look at the _answers_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use >= instead of ==

Tip: you can replace it with using of vscode CTRL + F (or CTRL + H)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ohh, it's been three years guys. I found the answer, and the upper answer is kinda true. Inside your `requirements.txt`, replace all the `==` with `>=` and save it. And do the `pip install -r requirements.txt` thingy. All done.