# WARNING: No metadata found in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages on PyCharm

Tags: python, django

Let's point out I have I have not added any `environment variables` or touched the `python paths`. The `environment variables`, I used where added beforehand from another heroku branch.  I was adding `AWS_Software` in the `Project.settings`, along with other software recommended by `Django` guide for `heroku`. when it needed to import storages when I ran `pip freeze > requirements.txt` this pops up:

```
WARNING: No metadata found in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
WARNING: No metadata found in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
WARNING: No metadata found in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
WARNING: No metadata found in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

Never ever had this issue until now, `committing` too `github` and pushing to `heroku` has no problems. I don't want to mess around with the python files.
I tried updating `Pip` and `Django` in the Python interpreter. Not luck with `Django` when getting to install on `requirements.txt(below)`

```
asgiref==3.4.1
boto3==1.18.5
botocore==1.21.5
certifi==2021.5.30
charset-normalizer==2.0.3
click==8.0.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.5
django-admin-honeypot==1.1.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-storages==1.11.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.2
Pillow==8.3.0
psycopg2==2.9.1
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.26.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
urllib3==1.26.6
whitenoise==5.3.0
```

Any possible solutions?
I ran:

```
print(os.environ['PATH'])

/home/user/PycharmProjects/Project/venv/bin/python /home/user/PycharmProjects/Project/blah.py
/home/user/PycharmProjects/Project/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/user/.dotnet/tools:/opt/mssql-tools/bin
```

Full path:

```
Home/user/PycharmProjects/Projects/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

**Update:**

I moved the requirements.txt to the full site-packages (above).
Tried it again no luck.

Comment: Please print your python environment path with `os.environ['PATH']`. What is the full path of "./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages"?

Answer (score 1):

After trial and error I ended up stumbling across this question:

[Upgrade python packages from requirements.txt using pip command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764549/upgrade-python-packages-from-requirements-txt-using-pip-command#43642296)

I tried:

```
pip install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt
```

ran:

```
 pip freeze > requirements.txt.
```

Then I ran again to be sure:

```
 pip install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt
```

Everything is working again and can be `updated` again.

My `packages` just needed to be `reinstalled`.