# Update requirements.txt without installing packages

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I have a `requirements.txt` with dependencies pinned using `==`. The pinning using `==` is a requirement to ensure reproducibility. I'd like to update all of them to the most recent version. I do not want to install any of them, I only want to modify `requirements.txt`

Comment: Please add some more details, or an example of what you are wanting to do. As written, this question is likely to be closed due to lack of details.

Comment: Well, packages mentioned in requirements.txt usually installed when you do `pip install -r requirements.txt `.

Comment: To always refer to latest version then you simply don't pin to a specific version number.

Comment: Short of gathering all the latest version numbers and updating requirements.txt, I don't think pip has a ready command to do what you want. This discussion  might give you pointers on how you can work out a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764549/upgrade-python-packages-from-requirements-txt-using-pip-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options for getting the latest package versions from PyPI described in [Python and pip, list all versions of a package that's available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available). If I take one that has an API that can be used within Python, e.g., the [answer describing using the luddite package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58661832/1862861), then you could do the following (after installing luddite itself):

Let's assume you have a `requirements.txt` file containing:

```
numpy==1.20.1
scipy==1.5.2
panda==1.5.3
```

then you could do:

```py
import luddite

requirements = []

# read in packages and get the latest versions
with open("requirements.txt", "r") as fp:
   for line in fp.readlines():
       package = line.strip().split("==")[0]

       # get latest version here
       latestversion = luddite.get_versions_pypi(package)[-1]
       requirements.append(f"{package}=={latestversion}")

# overwrite requirements.txt with latest versions
with open("requirements.txt", "w") as fp:
    for i, req in enumerate(requirements):
        fp.write(req)
        if i < len(requirements) - 1:
            fp.write("\n")
```

It should then (as of 23 May 2023) contain:

```
numpy==1.24.3
scipy==1.10.1
pandas==2.0.1
```