# how to download pip dependencies locally?

Tags: python, pip, cloud-foundry

I am running my python application that has `requirements.txt` file which contains various dependencies. I am deploying this application in a Pivotal Cloud Foundry environment. However, the environment I am deploying in it airgapped. Therefore I can't seem to get the dependencies.

The Git repo for python CF buildpack suggests that if an application has a `vendor` directory then it might get the dependencies from there: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack/blob/master/bin/steps/pip-install#L18

My question is, how can I download the dependencies mentioned in my `requirements.txt` file locally into a `vendor` folder?

Answer (score 12):

You can fetch all dependencies with the following command (an Internet connection is of course required)

```
pip download -r requirements.txt
```

Then, you can install offline those dependencies with the following command

> ```
> pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links file:///tmp/packages
> ```
>
> `--no-index` : Ignore package index (only looking at `--find-links`
>   URLs instead).
>
> `-f, --find-links <URL>` : If a URL or path to an html file, then
>   parse for links to archives. If a local path or `file://` URL that's a directory, then look for
>   archives in the directory listing.

This answer is taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-to-pip-install-packages-according-to-requirements-txt-from-a-local-directory)

Comment: If you find a duplicate, please close as such rather than copying over the answer.

Comment: Is `tmp/packages` the default location? Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 2):

Look at: http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/index.html#vendor-app-dependencies

tl;dr `pip install --download vendor -r requirements.txt`

Just use pip to install on the dev box and then check that in.

Comment: So my `requirements.txt` has `numpy` in it. I run the above command using docker container for CF: `docker run -v $PWD:/myapp -it cloudfoundry/cflinuxfs2 bash` then I install `pip` in that and then run `pip install --download vendor -r requirements.txt`. This downloads the files in my `vendor` directory. and one of the files is called `numpy-1.13.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`. However, when I try to push my application, I get an error `numpy-1.13.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64`