# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pip, cloud-foundry

I have `reqirements.txt` that has the line `numpy`. I run the following command to download the dependencies:

`pip install --download vendor -r requirements.txt`

This downloads all dependencies to the `vendor` folder and one of the file name is: `numpy-1.13.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

But when I `cf push` my application using the downloaded dependencies in the `vendor` folder, I get an error below:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: )`

Is there a way to resolve this? I believe this is happening because of the difference in the way the numpy file is named in vendor directory and the requirements.txt file.

My requirements.txt file contains the following:

```
flask-restful
Flask
numpy
Pillow==2.7.0
argparse==1.2.1
requests==2.5.1
boto3
boto
six==1.10.0
scikit-image
```

The error happens only on `numpy` and `scikit-image`. Other dependencies go ok.

This question is related to [how to download pip dependencies locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807039/how-to-download-pip-dependencies-locally)

Comment: How are you pointing your code to use the `vendor` folder?

Comment: That is dealt with cloudfoundry. The environment I use to deploy my application. But this is how they do it: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack/blob/master/bin/steps/pip-install#L18 My application has a `vendor` folder that contains all the downloaded dependencies.

Comment: So is this when you try to `cf push` the app that you get the error? *"run"* is a little unclear.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I get that error when I `cf push`. I was trying to make the question platform agnostic.

Comment: You might look at using miniconda instead.  It makes using things like numpy and scikit easier & the Python Build pack on Cloud Foundry supports it.  http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/#miniconda