# How to let pip search dependency packages in local directory?

Tags: python, pip

I have a server have limited access to network.

To install python packages you have to copy the packages onto the server.

For example, to install supervisor package I need to run below command:

```
pip install ./supervisor-3.3.4.tar.gz
```

The command need to be run in the directory where packages located.

But if supervisor have some dependency like meld3, then pip will try to find meld3 from internet, even the meld3 package also located in the same directory.

So how can I tell pip to find meld3 from local directory?

Comment: Try installing the dependencies first from the local directory

Comment: `pip install --no-index --find-links=./ ...`, Iirc. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-with-pip, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-to-pip-install-packages-according-to-requirements-txt-from-a-local-directory, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807039/how-to-download-pip-dependencies-locally