# Why can't my container find a pip installed package (via git)?

Tags: python, git, docker, pip

I have a Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
LABEL maintainer="info@martin-thoma.com"

# Settings for the local user to create
ENV APP_USER docker
ENV APP_USER_UID 9999
ENV APP_USER_GROUP docker
ENV APP_USER_GROUP_GID 4711
ENV PYTHONIOENCODING utf-8

# Install and update software
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --fix-missing git python-pip python-dev build-essential poppler-utils libmysqlclient-dev
RUN pip install pip --upgrade

# Copy projects code
COPY . /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Create user
RUN groupadd --gid ${APP_USER_GROUP_GID} ${APP_USER_GROUP} \
 && useradd --uid ${APP_USER_UID} --create-home -g ${APP_USER_GROUP} ${APP_USER} \
 && chown -R $APP_USER:$APP_USER_GROUP /opt/app

# Start app
USER docker
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/filestorage
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

and a `requirements.txt`

```
-e git+https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib.git@85eada6d59d0e2c757ef17c6ce143f3c976d2a90#egg=exchangelib
Flask==0.12.2
fuzzywuzzy==0.15.1
```

When I change the `exchangelib` line to `exchangelib` (hence not using git, but the version on PyPI) it works (but my code doesn't work as I need some of the recent changes).

When I have this, I get:

```
web_1  | ImportError: No module named exchangelib
```

What is the problem? **Why can't my container find a pip installed package (via git)?** How do I fix it?

My intuition is that the problem is that I install it as the root user, but the application runs as another user. The PyPI packages seem to get installed for all users while the editable is only local. But I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but maybe it's related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42982245/4557537

Comment: @Fadi I don't think so

Comment: If it helps, using your docker file etc, this works fine for me.

Comment: BTW, have you made sure that the `pip install ` step completes successfully?

Comment: @Leon I thought if `pip install` returns a non-zero exit code, then `docker-compose` would simply return an error? Besides this expectation, I didn't do any checks.

Comment: `-e` flag of `pip install` means *install in editable mode (i.e. setuptools "develop mode")* which is probably NOT what you really need. Try removing the `-e` switch from `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using

```
git+git://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib.git@85eada6d59d0e2c757ef17c6ce143f3c976d2a90#egg=exchangelib
```

as a line in the requirements.txt worked. No change in the docker file was necessary.