# Install library from downloaded pip files

Tags: tensorflow, pip

I want to download and install some specific library (it does not have to be tensorflow, but i ll use it as an example)

I have a ubuntu **virtual_machine_1** with internet connection.
I do:

```
pip download tensorflow
```

After downloading all the files in current folder, I transfer them into **virtual machine_2**
There I unpack files into folder_with_tf_dependencies and do:

```
pip install --user --find-links=../folder_with_tf_dependencies
```

The error I get is:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff735bbe090>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/tensorflow/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install packages using pip according to the requirements.txt file from a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-to-install-packages-using-pip-according-to-the-requirements-txt-file-from-a)

Comment: Add `--no-index`.