# 'RUN pip install -r requirements.txt' not working

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and trying to deploy a django project with the same. But after building the docker-compose I am getting this error:

> ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory: 'requirements.txt' ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build:
>   The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a
>   non-zero code: 1

I might be messing up in setting the correct path so here is my project structure

```
~/Desktop/Projects/ToDoApp
   ToDoApp
     settings.py
   docker-compose.yml
   Dockerfile
   manage.py
   requirements.txt
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
#pull official base image
FROM python:3

#set envionment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Adding requirements file
ADD requirements.txt ToDoApp/ToDoApp

#set work directory
WORKDIR /ToDoApp

#install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "./ToDoApp/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /ToDoApp/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
        - .:/Desktop/Projects/ToDoApp
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY = please_change_me
```

Comment: I think because you put `requirements.txt` in a subdirectory, `ToDoApp/ToDoApp/`, or, provided that subdir didn't exist, you renamed it to `ToDoApp/ToDoApp`.

Comment: Note that your `ADD` command uses a relative directory, while `WORKDIR` uses an absolute directory. Unless your Docker working directory was `/` first, I assume this won't be correct.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10429168/5463213) may help

Comment: my requirements.txt is in ToDoApp that's why i added it to ToDoApp/ToDoApp in my dockerfile. Where do you suggest thwefile should be?

Comment: do `WORKDIR /ToDoApp/ToDoApp ` and try

Comment: @JibinMathews it's giving the error ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: Cannot mkdir: /ToDoApp/ToDoApp is not a directory

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several issues I'm seeing:

- The ADD command you use creates a file called `ToDoApp/ToDoApp`, it doesn't even create a sub directory.
- ADD is unneeded (you're not extracting a tar or downloading from a URL) so that can switch to a COPY.
- You need to copy your code.
- The RUN commands can be reordered for better cache efficiency.
- Use relative paths and the WORKDIR correctly.
- Args need to be separated when you use the json syntax

The resulting Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3

#set envionment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# run this before copying requirements for cache efficiency
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

#set work directory early so remaining paths can be relative
WORKDIR /ToDoApp

# Adding requirements file to current directory
# just this file first to cache the pip install step when code changes
COPY requirements.txt .

#install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy code itself from context to image
COPY . .

# run from working directory, and separate args in the json syntax
CMD ["python", "./manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FROM python:3

#set envionment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#set work directory
WORKDIR /ToDoApp

# Adding requirements file
ADD requirements.txt /ToDoApp/

#install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "./ToDoApp/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"]
```