# Install all whl files from a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to gather files for an offline install of folder.

On one machine, I did `pip download -r requirements.txt -d wheelhouse`, where `wheelhouse` is a directory where all my whl's will be.

I then moved the wheelhouse directory to the remote machine (has no network access). I have miniconda installed on that machine. How can I install all whl files from that directory in one swift command?

Also, whenever I try to even install individual files (`pip install {path to.whl file}`), i'm getting

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
```

But I don't want to fetch it from an online repository as it's already on that machine.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Please show the exact command you used to install the wheel

Comment: pip install boto3-1.9.111-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: try upgrading pip on the remote machine and try again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install packages using pip according to the requirements.txt file from a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-to-install-packages-using-pip-according-to-the-requirements-txt-file-from-a)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline+install

Answer (score 12):

Move the wheels folder and install from there

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=wheels/ -r requirements.txt
```

"--no-index" argument avoids searching the PyPI indexes
"--find-links" is an array of locations to look for certain packages. You can pass it file paths, individual URLs to TAR or WHEEL files, HTML files, git repositories and more.

Comment: I'm using pip 23.2.1, but there is no --find-links option available?