# Deploying python application to staging and production

Tags: python, deployment, production, staging

I have a little application (it's Django, but that is likely not relevant; could be any python app) that I would like to deploy to a staging and eventually to a production server. My servers are FreeBSD, if that matters.

What I have working so far is a staging environment which has a webserver running that is able to talk to `gunicorn` which is serving the app. What I am struggling with now is updating the app.

The app was installed into a virtual environment (created using `virtualenvwrapper`) using an `sdist` tarball:

1. `python setup.py sdist`
2. copy `tar.gz` to staging server
3. `pip install <tarball>`

While this workflow achieved its goal, I have a bad feeling about it. For example, it does not let me (or I do not see how it would let me) use [pinned packages](https://nvie.com/posts/pin-your-packages/).

I am using `pip tools` to create a nice `requirements.txt` file, but that is not used in the process described above. If I am not mistaken, `pip install` will look at `setup.py`'s `install_requires` list. That is *not* my pinned dependencies.

An alternative I can think of is that I just `git checkout` to the server and use `python setup.py -e` or probably preferred `pip install --no-deps -e .` to "install" the app and then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. But that also seems odd (the git checkout might copy unneeded stuff to the server, for example).

Likely it would be possible to use a local "index" that only has the packages in the versions I want (similar to the question [How to install packages using pip according to the requirements.txt file from a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10429168/254868) on SO) but this also seems slightly odd (and laborious/error prone).

I imagine this is a common problem/question; yet my google-fu let me down. I have tried

- [The Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/)
- [Django Deployment Workshop](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920014089.do) (from July 2010!)
- Gitlab CI/CD tutorials
- Stackoverflow
- Google/Youtube with various search terms

What are reasonable options for deploying python applications in a staging > production workflow that allow for tight control of the installed dependencies?

Comment: I don't think there's any once answer to this that isn't opinionated.  I usually just put pinned dependencies in `requirements.txt`, install those with `pip install -r requirements.txt`, and then install my package.  I would see the package itself and the staging/production environments and any steps for reproducing them as related but separate.

Comment: I will have 2 Git branch (master/staging), develop in staging, keep my `requirements.txt`, `.gitignore` files up to date in order to avoid `unneeded stuff to the server` (why is that possible ?). After I'm ready for deploy. Move to the prod server, `git fetch/merge` + `pip install -e . --upgrade` + restart/reload server if needed. Only your code/deps changes so why would that not work for your case ?  Otherwise, I like the `conda env update --file path_to_the_awesome_yaml_file --prune` command as it get rids of unneeded deps too.

Comment: @Iguananaut: granted, the package can be seen different from its deployment (environment). But the question then is: how does the `requirements.txt´ file get to the staging/production (or any other) environment? It is not part of the package/sdist, as far as I can tell. Is this just a separate "copy job"?

Comment: @funilrys: `stuff on the server` in my case would for example be IDE cruft which is in the git repo (maybe that's bad practice in itself?). Also I could imagine that there is test data in the git repo which is not required on prod? Also, currently, prod does not have access to the git repo; but that's a separate thing and can be changed.

Comment: BTW: thank you guys for replying super fast. The python community rocks!

Comment: Yeah I mostly deploy with Docker containers these days anyways so it's usually a matter of copying my requirements.txt into the image and running pip on it (possibly deleting it afterwards but usually not since it can be useful for inspection). I don't know exactly how you're doing your deployments but you can just as well do the same. If you really wanted you could also do something like have your `setup.py` optionally read from a `requirements.txt` included in the source tarball, depending on the value of an environment variable or something.