# Install ImageMagick and Ghostscript through Python

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am very new to Python.

I have an OCR program that uses Tesseract, ImageMagick and Ghostscript. I created a .exe file to give it to my team so that they can use it on their tool.

The problem that I am facing is that all of them will have to separately install ImageMAgick and Ghostscript. Also Tesseract.

I am using Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

Can you guys please tell me how can I make a .exe that will install all of these in the user's system and be able to run to execute my python program.

I am also OK to have the ImageMagick, Ghostscript and Tesseract folders be placed somewhere and then are declared as environ variables. Please guide.

Comment: You can distribute the project as Python source and have your team [install it from a local directory while taking the dependencies into consideration automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-to-install-packages-using-pip-according-to-the-requirements-txt-file-from-a)

Comment: Apologies for sounding like a caveman, so are you telling me that I have to have all the software I need to install in a folder and make a list with requirement.txt. i can do pip install only if python is installed. but in this case it won't be for the others. basically what I'm asking is I want an installer

Comment: there are programs that create installers for any executable and its supporting files (google something like "create installer for Windows"), but then you'll have to know where exactly the Python interpreter in the `.exe` file created by py2exe or what have you will look for these libraries. Once you get to know that, instruct the installer to put the libraries in that directory. But then the resulting installer's size will be in the hundreds of megabytes. It may be easier to ask your team to install Python and use pip to install and update your software