# Installing packages present in requirements.txt by referencing it from a python file

Tags: python, pip

I have the following `requirements.txt` file :

```
beautifulsoup4=4.8.2==py37_0
urllib3=1.25.8=py37_0
pyopenssl=19.1.0=py37_0
openssl=1.1.1d=h1de35cc_4
pandas=1.0.1=py37h6c726b0_0
tqdm=4.42.1=py_0
```

I need to install all these packages, or make sure they are installed from within a python script. How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install packages using pip according to the requirements.txt file from a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-to-install-packages-using-pip-according-to-the-requirements-txt-file-from-a)

Comment: No it does not answer my question as I need to install packages from the file and can't execute the commands from the local directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)

Comment: The code installs a single package whereas I needed to install all packages from requirements.txt file.

Comment: @Subramanian I know, you just need to adjust the _pip_ command to your needs. See my full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way can be like this:

```
import os
import sys
os.system(f'{sys.executable} -m pip install -r requirements.txt') #take care for path of file
```

More controls (*and corner case handlings*) over calling the command can be taken by subprocess as @sinoroc said, and in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) too.

One command that docs suggest is:

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'my_package'])
```

which is a wrapper over `subprocess.call`.

Comment: This works, although I think `os` has to be installed beforehand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No it doesnt have to be installed it is a built-in module

Comment: This is wrong and will most likely not give the expected results in some cases. Unreliable. -- Use the following instead: `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'])` -- [Reference](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program)

Comment: @sinoroc What are the cases?

Comment: `pip` is not always guaranteed to be associated with the current running Python interpreter.

Comment: @sinoroc And why is that? Also, how is running the command from subprocess preventing it?

Comment: Because of [this](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/). This is the `[sys.executable, '-m', 'pip']` part that prevents this from happening, it make sure that _pip_ is run with the exact same Python interpreter executable as the one currently running. `subprocess.check_call` is better than `os.system` because it checks that the executed program ended successfully, among other things.

Comment: @sinoroc Thanks for giving information. I added that part in the answer.  You were right, as docs say here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system

Comment: Thanks for adding this, and I'd gladly change my vote if you remove the first part completely as it is simply bad advice.

Comment: @sinoroc I think reader of this answer will get  to know both ways and will know the pros and cons thing, which seems to be good at its place.

Comment: @Vicrobot At least fix the first suggestion to something like `os.system(f'{sys.executable} -m pip -r requirements.txt')`.

Comment: @sinoroc yes, that's an improvement. Edited. Your comment is missing 'install' part though.

Comment: Thanks for making the change. Thanks for noticing the missing `install`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
import subprocess
import sys

command = [
    sys.executable,
    '-m',
    'pip',
    'install',
    '--requirement',
    'requirements.txt',
]

subprocess.check_call(command)
```

It is very important to use `sys.executable` to get the path to the current running Python interpreter and use it with `-m pip` (*executable module*) to make 100% sure that *pip* installs for that particular interpreter. Indeed calling just `pip` (*script*) delivers absolutely no guarantee as to what Python interpreter will be called, `pip` could be associated with any Python interpreter on the system.

Additionally [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) ensures that an error is raised if the process does not end successfully (i.e. the installation didn't succeed).

Advice such as the following is unreliable, if not dangerous:

- <del>`os.system('pip install -r requirements.txt')`</del>

---

**References**:

- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program
- [Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command `pip install -r requirements.txt` when in the same directory as the txt file

Or in python using

```
import os
os.system ('pip install -r path/to/requirements.txt')
```

Comment: I need to run it from the python script itself. I need to send it to my team lead and he just wants to execute the python script.

Comment: This is wrong and will most likely not give the expected results in some cases. Unreliable. -- Use the following instead: `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'])` -- [Reference](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program)