# Pycharm change venv python from 3.6 to 3.7 without creating all enviroment from strach

Tags: pycharm, virtualenv, python-venv, virtual-environment

I work on pycharm project and I have a virtual environment (venv) with Python version 3.6.

I need to change it to 3.7 but I don't want to have to create a new environment and install all the packages from the beginning.
Is there a way to do that?
Just change the python version while keeping all the packages?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. Your Python executable is what you have inside your virtual environment. To change that you have to remove your venv and create it again using a different version of Python.

Comment: @OmidShojaee Thanks, is there a way to easily install all packages from the python3.6 venv once I created the venv with Python3.7?

Comment: @okuoub [write a requirement file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7225900) or a shell script to execute the commands for you.

Comment: @bad_coder Not a dup — the OP doesn't have a local directory with packages. A venv with installed packages is not suitable.

Comment: @phd the question is `venv` specific (otherwise it would lack focus because any number of package managers could be recommended -  but that's not what is asked). You say "a venv isn't suitable" but in fact it works and that's what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @bad_coder I meant old venv for Python 3.6 is not suitable to install packages for Python 3.7. The TS should either install from PyPI or download packages from PyPI and install from that directory, not from the old venv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately what you are looking for is not possible.

Your solution is to create a `requirements.txt` file from your current environment, create a new one with Python 3.7 and re-install the packages.

To create the file, issue this while your **current** environment is active:

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

And then, this one when the **new** environment is installed and active:

`pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt`

P.S: `requirements.txt` is just a name everyone uses. It's not written in stone. Use any filename you want.