# Python Script to run shell commend within a Proxmox lxc Container

Tags: python, lxc, proxmox

I am trying to write a python script to run a python code in a `proxmox lxc container`.
To do this, I need to install packages and requirements file for the python code in the container using a python script.

But I don't know what the solution is.

I hope your kind response.
Thank you.

Comment: you can put the required libraries in a requirements.txt file and execute `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all the libraries at once. you can put this instruction in a script in any language you want, including a python script. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-can-i-install-packages-using-pip-according-to-the-requirements-txt-file-from

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what I need is how to handling the proxmox lxc container on my local machine using python script or ansible playbook.