# python: installing pygame to every new project

Tags: python, pip, pygame

I ran into some problems with some pip installations. I have found a way of installing that works, but I feel like it's wrong.

I installed pygame from the cmd prompt and got this message:

> ```
> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not
> writeable Requirement already satisfied: pygame in
> c:\users\Somenewguy\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages
> (2.1.2)
> ```

But when I went to pycharm and started my project, I got this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Somenewguy\Python Projects\new\main.py", line 1, in <module>
     import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I then did the pygame pip installation from the terminal in pycharm. But this time I installed it directly into the project folder, and that approach worked.
This is the only way I can import pygame into my projects which I think is weird.

Why do I have to install this package for each project?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a [virtual-environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html), this is the expected behavior. If you don't want to install it every time, use the system environnement.

Comment: If thats the case, look to see if the repo has a requirements.txt and call `pip install -r requirements.txt` to get all of them. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-can-i-install-packages-using-pip-according-to-the-requirements-txt-file-from)