# How can I write a requirements file to pip install from multiple submodules?

Tags: pip, python-packaging

I have a master repo with repositories checked out at certain commits. All individual repositories are installable with the command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

from within the master-repository, I want to make it so you can install all the packages at once. The file structure is like:

```
├── aws_login_handler
│   ├── AWSLoginHandler
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── setup.py
├── datamodels
│   ├── BATDataModels
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── setup.py
├── gribmanager
│   ├── GribManager
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── setup.py
├── mongobase
│   ├── MongoBase
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── setup.py
├── pyrtz
│   ├── PyRTZ
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── setup.py
├── routingserver
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── RoutingServer
│   └── setup.py
├── runrouting
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── RunRouting
│   └── setup.py
├── weatherrouting_v3
│   ├── BATWeatherRouting
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── setup.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Where I have added the requirements file:

```
-r ./datamodels/requirements.txt
-r ./mongobase/requirements.txt
-r ./routingserver/requirements.txt
-r ./runrouting/requirements.txt
-r ./weatherrouting_v3/requirements.txt
-r ./aws_login_handler/requirements.txt
-r ./gribmanager/requirements.txt
```

However when I run the command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

From the top level strucutre, the error:

```
ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

Is printed.

How can I create a way to install all the requirements of the sub modules?

Comment: I think this is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10429168/3202440 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe a stray single dot `.` somewhere in one of the `requirements.txt` files. Without having access to the files or even the full terminal output, it is difficult to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a relative path (`./`) you must add a `setup.py` in your main requirements folder.

Have a look at
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#argument-handling