# How do I create a "package.json" file? Git clone repository is missing a package.json file

Tags: python, django

Am new to coding, I have cloned this GitHub repository

https://github.com/TribeZOAGit/zoa_ussd

it happens to be missing the package.json file, so how do I create a package.json file for the already existing project.

I can't tell which dependencies.

npm init command creates the package.json file but with no dependencies.

After I cloned the repo, npm start throwing error

"Missing script start"
Then I found package.json file was missing

npm init was meant to create the file but packages were not in the file, neither were dependencies nor scripts.

How do I addresse this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a Python repository, not JavaScript...

`requirements.txt` is `pip`'s version of `npm`'s `package.json`

See [what is PIP](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_pip.asp)

See [here](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pip-install-requirements/#:%7E:text=Install%20packages%20with%20pip%3A%20%2Dr%20requirements.txt,-The%20following%20command&text=You%20can%20name%20the%20configuration,%2Fto%2Frequirements.txt%20.) for information on installing the necessary packages using `pip`.

Or [this Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225900/how-can-i-install-packages-using-pip-according-to-the-requirements-txt-file-from)